# How do I disable menu-bar-mode only for tty frames?

Tags: terminal-emacs, menu-bar

I run both gui frames and tty frames on the same server. I'd like to only have the gui frames have the menu-bar and I want all tty frames to not have a menu bar.

I'm confused by the menu bar docs, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function `display-graphic-p` returns `nil` for non-GUI Emacs. So something like the following should work:

```
(unless (display-graphic-p)
   (menu-bar-mode -1))
```

## EDIT

My original answer only works for Emacs run only in a tty. Since you are using both GUI and TTY frames run from the same server, you need to modify individual frame parameters:

```
(defun contextual-menubar (&optional frame)
  "Display the menubar in FRAME (default: selected frame) if on a
    graphical display, but hide it if in terminal."
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-parameter frame 'menu-bar-lines 
                             (if (display-graphic-p frame)
                                  1 0)))

(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'contextual-menubar)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956521/how-can-i-hide-the-menu-bar-from-a-specific-frame-in-emacs

Comment: Where would I put that? Like a `before-make-frame-hook`?

Comment: I tried `before-make-frame-hook` and that did not work.

Comment: The recommendation from Emacs dev is to use `display-graphic-p` now, instead of `window-system`. I forget why. ;-) (But either will work.)

Comment: Works for me thanks! Could you please remove the trailing space after `menu-bar-lines`?